# StatusBar plugin can't build due to @ionic-native/core missing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I installed the [StatusBar plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar) based on the documentation:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
```

But, when I ran the app locally with `ionic serve` (or, if I wanted to make the production build with `ionic build --prod`) I got:

`ERROR in node_modules/@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx/index.d.ts(1,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ionic-native/core'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple solution, which did not have a direct hit either on Google or StackOverflow, was to install the missing core module like this:

`npm install @ionic-native/core`

After this, the build went through fine.

Hope this helps someone.